# Kendo-Knockout reference with MVC using Database First Approach

Tags: model-view-controller, knockout.js, kendo-ui, knockout-mvc

I am looking for Kendo-Knockout reference with MVC using Database First Approach.

Please look at my code below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;

        self.Id = ko.observable();
        self.Name = ko.observable();
        self.Category = ko.observable();
        self.Price = ko.observable();

        var Product = {
            Id: self.Id,
            Name: self.Name,
            Category: self.Category,
            Price: self.Price
        };

        self.Product = ko.observable();
        self.Products = ko.observableArray();

        $.getJSON("/Product/GetProoducts", function (data) {
            self.Products(data);
            $.each(data, function (index) {

             })
        });


        self.Create = function () {
            if (Product.Name() != "" && Product.Price() != "" && Product.Category() != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("AddProduct", "Product")',
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: ko.toJSON(Product),
                    success: function (data) {
                        self.Products.push(data);
                        self.Name("");
                        self.Price("");
                        self.Category("");

                    }
                }).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                    alert(err);
                });
            }
        }
}

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

I am getting an issue with the above code. I need to do CRUD operation using kendo - knockout js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below code ,

**Repository**

```
 interface IProductRepository : IDisposable
{
    IEnumerable<Product> GetAll();
    Product Get(int id);
    Product Add(Product item);
    bool Update(Product item);
    bool Delete(int id);
    void Save();
}
```

public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository, IDisposable
    {

```
    RepositoryEntities context = null;

    public ProductRepository()
    {
        context = new RepositoryEntities();
    }

    public ProductRepository(RepositoryEntities context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()
    {
       return context.Products.ToList();
    }

    public Product Get(int id)
    {
        return context.Products.Find(id);
    }

    public Product Add(Product item)
    {
        Product newProduct = context.Products.Add(item);
        int id = context.SaveChanges();
        return newProduct;
    }

    public bool Update(Product item)
    {
        context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }

    public bool Delete(int id)
    {
        Product objProduct = context.Products.Find(id);
        context.Products.Remove(objProduct);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
   // private IProductRepository productRepository;
    private IProductRepository repository = new ProductRepository();


    //public ProductController(IProductRepository repository)
    //{
    //    this.productRepository = repository;
    //}


    //
    // GET: /Product/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetProoducts()
    {
        return Json(repository.GetAll(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult AddProduct(Product item)
    {
        item = repository.Add(item);
        return Json(item, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult EditProduct(int id, Product product)
    {
        product.Id = id;
        if (repository.Update(product))
        {
            return Json(repository.GetAll(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json(null);
    }


    public JsonResult DeleteProduct(int id)
    {
        if (repository.Delete(id))
        {
            return Json(new { Status = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json(new { Status = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<script src="~/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/knockout-kendo.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/kendo.silver.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="body">
    <h2>Kendo Knockout CRUD Operations</h2>
    <div data-bind="kendoGrid: { data : Products,  rowTemplate: 'rowTmpl', scrollable: true, sortable: true, useKOTemplates: true}">
    </div>
    <script id="rowTmpl" type="text/html">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Price"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Category"></td>
            <td> <button data-bind="click: $root.Edit">Edit</button></td>
            <td> <button data-bind="click: $root.Delete">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
    </script>
    <br/>
    <div data-bind="if: Product">
        <div>
            <h2>Update Product</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="productId" data-bind="visible: false">ID</label>
            <label data-bind="text: Product().Id, visible: false"></label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input data-bind="value: Product().Name" type="text" title="Name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="category">Category</label>
            <input data-bind="value: Product().Category" type="text" title="Category" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="price">Price</label>
            <input data-bind="value: Product().Price" type="text" title="Price" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
            <button data-bind="click: $root.Update">Update</button>
            <button data-bind="click: $root.Cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div data-bind="ifnot: Product()">
            <div>
                <h2>Add New Product</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input data-bind="value: $root.Name" type="text" title="Name" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <input data-bind="value: $root.Price" type="text" title="Price" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <input data-bind="value: $root.Category" type="text" title="Category" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <button data-bind="click: $root.Create">Save</button>
                <button data-bind="click: $root.Reset">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var ViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;

            self.Id = ko.observable();
            self.Name = ko.observable();
            self.Category = ko.observable();
            self.Price = ko.observable();

            var Product = {
                Id: self.Id,
                Name: self.Name,
                Category: self.Category,
                Price: self.Price
            };

            self.Product = ko.observable();
            self.Products = ko.observableArray();

            $.getJSON("/Product/GetProoducts", function (data) {
                self.Products(data);
                $.each(data, function (index) {

                 })
            });


            self.Create = function () {
                if (Product.Name() != "" && Product.Price() != "" && Product.Category() != "") {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("AddProduct", "Product")',
                        cache: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        data: ko.toJSON(Product),
                        success: function (data) {
                            self.Products.push(data);
                            self.Name("");
                            self.Price("");
                            self.Category("");

                        }
                    }).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                        alert(err);
                    });
                }
            }


            self.Reset = function () {
                self.Name("");
                self.Price("");
                self.Category("");
            }


            // Edit product details
            self.Edit = function (Product) {
                self.Product(Product);
            }


            // Cancel product Details
            self.Cancel = function () {
                self.Product(null);
            }

            //Update Product Details
            self.Update = function () {
                var Product = self.Product();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("EditProduct", "Product")',
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: ko.toJSON(Product),
                    success: function (data) {
                        self.Products.removeAll();
                        self.Products(data); //Put the response in ObservableArray
                        self.Product(null);
                        alert("Record Updated Successfully");
                    }
                }).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, err) { alert(err); });
            }


            //Delete  Product Details
            self.Delete = function (Product) {
                if (confirm('Are you sure to Delete "' + Product.Name + '" product ??'))
                {
                    var id = Product.Id;

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Product/DeleteProduct/'+ id,
                        cache: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        data: ko.toJSON(id),
                        success: function (data) {
                            self.Products.remove(Product);

                        }
                    }).fail(
                    function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                        self.status(err);
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
    });
</script>
```

Please find below links too,
http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/knockout/0bOU010413-Knockout-CRUD-Operations-using-MVC4.html

http://pinaki-mukherjee.blogspot.in/2013/01/kendo-knockout-grid-bind.html
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yusufkaratoprak/asp-net-mvc-with-knockout-js/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640294/Learning-MVC-Part-Generic-Repository-Pattern-in